# Adding an audio trace with JCodec for Android

Tags: android, audio, video

I would like to use JCodec for Android for generate a video clip which is simply a slideshow.

Is it possible to add an audio trace to a video clip with JCodec?

Comment: What have you achieved till yet ?

Comment: Nothing... I've not received any reply. I've also sent an email to the email address in the JCodec webpage but I've not received any reply!